# kubelet version of eks-fargate and ec2 instance does not match

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have the following fargate nodes and ec2 instances in my eks cluster. The kubelet version are not the same for all the nodes.

```
fargate-ip-10-11-154-126.ca-central-1.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   3m30s   v1.22.6-eks-14c7a48
fargate-ip-10-11-154-240.ca-central-1.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   130m    v1.22.6-eks-14c7a48
ip-10-11-130-49.ca-central-1.compute.internal            Ready    <none>   3h4m    v1.22.10-eks-7dc61e8
ip-10-11-151-52.ca-central-1.compute.internal            Ready    <none>   3d23h   v1.22.10-eks-7dc61e8
ip-10-11-157-227.ca-central-1.compute.internal           Ready    <none>   4d23h   v1.22.10-eks-7dc61e8

I tried to restart the fargate pods so that the fargate node would be updated, but that did not help.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected; Fargate runs a kubelet that is the same version as the control plane, where the minor version can be different from those running on EC2 like your screen shown.